# Given the following image, find the measures of angles 1, 2, 3, 4 in terms of $\theta$

Tags: geometry

[image]

It is given that AB=AC and CD is a diameter.

I can find m$\angle$1 and m$\angle$2 using the isosceles triangle theorem, the euclidean angle sum, and the inscribed angle theorems. I find that these are both equal to 180-2$\theta$. However, I can't seem to find a good way to find m$\angle$3 and m$\angle$4 because anything I do seems to just take me back to obvious equalities. Any suggestions on what I might do?

Comment: **Hint:** Concentrate on arcs.

Comment: Use the information that $CD$ is a diameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: the angle $\angle CBD$ is right.